# how to pass dynamic value with in sql query

Tags: c#

```
int i = int.Parse(rid);
SqlConnection thisconnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\lagenius\JIvandhara ngo\JIvandhara ngo\ngo.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
thisconnection.Open();
string st = ("select  receipt_no, name, rupees, pay_by, date from receipt_info where receipt_no = 4");
DataSet thisdataset = new DataSet();
//string cmdtext = "select * from receipt_info where receipt_no =='" + i + "'";
SqlCommand cmd = new  SqlCommand(st, thisconnection);
SqlDataAdapter data_ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
data_ad.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When asking questions you should; provide a short description of your problem, what you have tried, the actual and expected result, and then ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string st = ("select  receipt_no, name, rupees, pay_by, date from receipt_info where receipt_no =" + i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string st = string.Format("select receipt_no, name, rupees, pay_by, date from receipt_info where receipt_no = {0}",i);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should rewrite your statement using parameter

```
string st = "select  receipt_no, name, rupees, pay_by, date from receipt_info where receipt_no = @Receipt_Number";
```

And when you've created your `SqlCommand` - you should add parameter @Receipt_Number to it

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Receipt_Number", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@Receipt_Number"].Value = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

When sending parameterized queries, you should use [`SqlParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx). An example of how to use them are available at http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Basically you structure your query with placeholders, and fill them using the [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx)s [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) property.

```
int searchId = 4;
string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\lagenius\JIvandhara ngo\JIvandhara ngo\ngo.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
        "select  receipt_no, name, rupees, pay_by, date " +
        "from receipt_info where receipt_no = @Id", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Id", searchId));
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
        }
    }
}
```